# How to test a method in componentDidMount() with Jest and Enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I want to cover the code below with unit test:

```
export class DataTrack extends Component<DataTrackProps> {
componentDidMount() {
    this.setData();
    
    if (this.props.enableDataTrack) {
        this.pushData();
    }
}

private setData() {
    window.globalData = {
        app_platform        : "I"
    }
}

private getData() {
        this.dataTrack= {
            command: "EVENT",
            name: "data",
            data: {
                app_embed_name : "it"
            }
        };

        return this.dataTrack;
}

private pushData() {
    window.analyticsData = window.analyticsData || [];
    window.analyticsData .push(this.getData());
}
}
```

and started with covering the `componentDidMount` with the test below:

```
it("should run the methods in the componentDidMount", () => {
    const props: DataTrackProps= {
        enableDataTrack: true,
    };

    const setDataOnMount = jest.spyOn(DataTrack.prototype, 'setData'); // spy
    const wrapper = shallow(<DataTrack{...props}  />); // create
    expect(setDataOnMount ).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // test
});
```

But I'm getting the error:
`Argument of type '"setData"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FunctionPropertyNames<Required<DataTrack>>'.`

I also don't know how to test the methods `setData`, `getData` and `pushData` with Jest/Enzyme.

Can someone help me with this?
How can I cover the methods inside the `componentDidMount` and the methods self?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test if the `window.globalData` and `window.analyticsData` are set with the correct value. There is no need to install spy to the private methods.

Besides, you should restore `window.globalData` and `window.analyticsData` property to the initial state. Avoid test cases influencing each other.

E.g.

`DataTrack.tsx`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

declare global {
  interface Window {
    globalData: any;
    analyticsData: any;
  }
}

interface DataTrackProps {
  enableDataTrack?: boolean;
}
export class DataTrack extends Component<DataTrackProps> {
  dataTrack = {};
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setData();
    if (this.props.enableDataTrack) {
      this.pushData();
    }
  }

  private setData() {
    window.globalData = { app_platform: 'I' };
  }

  private getData() {
    this.dataTrack = {
      command: 'EVENT',
      name: 'data',
      data: {
        app_embed_name: 'it',
      },
    };
    return this.dataTrack;
  }

  private pushData() {
    window.analyticsData = window.analyticsData || [];
    window.analyticsData.push(this.getData());
  }
  render() {
    return <div>data track</div>;
  }
}
```

`DataTract.test.tsx`:

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';
import { DataTrack } from './DataTract';

describe('DataTract', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    window.globalData = undefined;
    window.analyticsData = undefined;
  });
  test('should push and set data', () => {
    shallow(<DataTrack enableDataTrack />);
    expect(window.globalData).toEqual({ app_platform: 'I' });
    expect(window.analyticsData).toEqual([
      {
        command: 'EVENT',
        name: 'data',
        data: {
          app_embed_name: 'it',
        },
      },
    ]);
  });

  test('should set data', () => {
    shallow(<DataTrack enableDataTrack={false} />);
    expect(window.globalData).toEqual({ app_platform: 'I' });
    expect(window.analyticsData).toBeUndefined();
  });
});
```

test result:

```sh
 PASS  examples/70364599/DataTract.test.tsx (8.509 s)
  DataTract
    ✓ should push and set data (5 ms)
    ✓ should set data

---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File           | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files      |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 DataTract.tsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.315 s, estimated 10 s
```